# Android Map Zoom Event Trigger

Tags: android, maps

Is there anyway to know if the map is completely loaded? whenever i zoom and the map is still loading at the new zoom level, i want to show a progress bar or something of that sort till the map load is complete,i want to be able to trigger an event from the time the zoom is pressed till the map is fully-loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible, Google handles all these event internally in its API see also: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html